# Zeppelin connection refused

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Zeppeling notebook is reporting an "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect". I tried a few simple python statements. Is this the notebook losing connection to the Web Server? I don't see a lot of chat about Zeppelin on SO. It's hard to troubleshoot.

```
 INFO [2016-12-12 19:23:37,006] ({pool-1-thread-7} Paragraph.java[jobRun]:252) - run paragraph 20161212-191758_314125131 using null org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter@6bf78ad0
ERROR [2016-12-12 19:23:38,003] ({pool-1-thread-7} Job.java[run]:189) - Job failed
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:328)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterprete
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that error isn't connection problem to webserver, but looks like Spark connection problem. In case you didn't intent to use Spark there (and use Python as before), you should specify the name of interpreter in the beginning of each paragaraph in Zeppelin (`python`, `spark`, etc). If you don't specify, it uses default bound interpreter in your list of interpreters, and by default it's `spark` with scala. Thus:

1) in case of using python, should add `%python` in the beginning of that paragraph

2) in case of intended use of spark interpreter, your version of Zeppelin and whether you're using SPARK_HOME would be helpful.

Comment: That is correct, the reason 2nd paragraph fails is - as the input does not start with `%python`, it is interpreted by Zeppelin using the default binded interpreter from the [list of interpreters](http://zeppelin.apache.org/supported_interpreters.html), available for this notebook.
One can see the list of available interpreters under the 'cog' icon, and change the default one by drab-n-drop it to the first place in the list.

Comment: Thank you and I've figured it out later on.